# Word order after "as"

Tags: word-order, subordinate-clauses

could someone help with the word order in the following sentence?

"Please note it down as it will shortly be necessary."

Should I flip here "shortly" and "be"? Is the placement of "shortly" correct with respect to "necessary"?

"It" is a sort of a password specified in the preceding sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative could be:

> "Please note it down as this will be needed shortly."

or:

> "Please note this down as it will be needed shortly."

You could further emphasise by elaborating what is to be noted by adding it after the *this* ("Please note this *phone number* down as it will be need shortly.").

Comment: Thus, the presence of "as" does not change the word order here? I am just coming off learning German, which has messed up my English a bit.

Comment: It does not change.